# Why this javascript trigger is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show abox when a table row is clicked:

Js

```
$("#rowID").click(function(){
    var User = document.getElementById("userID");
    var Box = document.getElementById("userBox");

    document.Box.style.display = "block";
});
```

HTML

```
<tr id="rowID" href="#">
                          <td id="userID"><?php echo $datum['ID']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $datum['Account']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $datum['Date']; ?></td>
                          <td><span class="label label-warning">Pending</span></td>
                          <td><?php echo $datum['Email']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: `document.Box` is not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need another prepending `document.` to `Box`. You're basically saying `document.document.getElementById('userBox')`.

Also, you might aswell just make everything JQuery since you're using it to assign an EventListener to `#rowId`.

Also, since there will be multiple rows, you might want to make `#rowID` into a class, e.g. `.row` since an ID should be uniquely identifiable to one element.

```js
$(".row").click(function(){
    var user = $("#userID");
    var box = $("#userBox");

    box.show();
});
```

```css
#userBox {
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row" href="#">
            <td id="userID">Hello</td>
            <td>World!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row" href="#">
            <td id="userID">Foo</td>
            <td>Bar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="userBox">I'm a box!</div>
```

Comment: Should be `Box.show()` according to whats defined. However convention would dictate to declare both box and user with lower case first-letters.

Comment: @Aubricus Yes you're absolutely right, typo* Thanks!

Comment: It worked with Box.show, do you guys know any good place to learn jQuery?

Comment: @MisterKnuckles Any console errors? From the code you've sent, this should work. We can't see the element with the ID `userBox` in the code you've sent, though

Comment: @TobyMellor worked with Box.show, edited my last comment but it was too late for you to read it xD, do you know any good tutorial for jQuery, maybe, how to do an ajax call with jQuery :?

Comment: @MisterKnuckles Code Academy? It's just a lot of trial and error like you're doing. If the solution worked, please make sure to mark it as correct! :) Thanks

Comment: @MisterKnuckles https://api.jquery.com/ https://learn.jquery.com/ https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery (I literally just googled "learning jquery")

Comment: @MisterKnuckles while your at it, you might be interested in JS best practices: http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/ https://github.com/airbnb/javascript